# Highlight text which a specific regex matches, live

Tags: vim

I'm working on some code, where I know that if a certain regex finds a match in the file, it's a syntax error.

I want to be able to specify a list of file types, each with a list of regexs, which will be automatically highlighted as I type them on a file of that file type.

Example:

I'll have a regex like `/new$/` on file type `foo`. If I type `new` in a line, it should highlight that text (preferable) or the line. If I press enter at that point, it should be kept highlighted. If I type a character after it, the highlight should immediately go away.

Is this possible in vim?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the existing syntax files you may want one of the following:

```
" Somewhere in the vimrc
augroup vimrcFoo
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType,WinEnter * :if &ft is# 'foo' | 
                                \    silent! call matchadd('Error', 'new$', -1, 42) |
                                \endif
augroup END

" In after/syntax/foo.vim
syntax match Error /foo$/ containedin=@ALL
```

. Last one may break existing syntax rules. First one is preferred if your case has nothing to do with actually syntax (it won’t spoil it, just override highlighting). In order to delete highlighting in the first case you have to use `call matchdelete(42)`.